# samba share mount owner is colord

Tags: samba, authorization, transmission

My hair is falling out already on the account of samba share issues.

- I have an ext4 samba share on a raspberry pi, with a mask `0777` specified.
- Only `myuser` on raspberry can authenticate via samba.
- `chmod -R` and `chown` were run on the folders to fix (self-created)
  authorization issues.
- `myuser` was added to group `debian-transmission` in order to access
  torrented files properly from my laptop.
- From my notebook I access files with `myuser` with the appropriate password via samba.

Now, newly downloaded files and folders have the owner `colord` and group `avahi-autoipd`, and I cannot make sense of it. I also have only read access from the notebook. How can I fix this?

Edit: the owner on the server is `debian-transmission`, the owner checked with `ls -l` is `colors`, with group `avahi-autopid`...

Edit2: per @X Tian's comment, the uid and gid on the notebook indeed equals to user and group `debian-transmission` on the samba server.

Comment: From where do you down load & look at the actual user ID/group I'd of the downloaded files not name since it really works with id's and names are worked out by `ls` using `/etc/passwd`

Comment: Sorry, I mean use `-n` option on ls to look at actual numeric id's not their name translation because passed file may have different names for those id's.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be two possible options to solve your problem.

1. Try to add to `[global]` section in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

   ```
   force user = myuser
   force group = debian-transmission
   ```
2. Second option. I'm not sure if it works, but you should try if first method fails. Add sticky bit to shared folder.

   ```
   chmod 2770 SHARED_FOLDER
   find SHARED_FOLDER -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;
   ```